# Closed as not constructive, why?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

What hoops didn't I jump through with [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/38189/what-amount-of-php-memory-usage-is-reasonable-for-multiple-wordpress-sites)?

I'm not sure why it wasn't constructive.  I'm also sure I'm not the only guy with a bunch of WordPress sites out there.  Certainly someone could tell me, "Dude, you need to do X" or "Yeah, that's high, check your plugin usage with Y" or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for bringing this inquiry to meta - I've reviewed your question and I believe that it was closed on the grounds that it does not meet the "practical, answerable" criteria from the [FAQ](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq):

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual
>   problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the
>   usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an
>   entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.
>
> If your motivation for asking the question is "I would like to
>   participate in a discussion about ______", then you should not be
>   asking here.
>
> However, if your motivation is "I would like others to
>   explain ______ to me", then you are probably OK.
>
> (Discussions are of course welcome in our [real time web chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).)

Determining how PHP is using memory requires a great deal of information - even if this information were provided up-front, responses to your question could be expected to vary widely between respondents (the topics of OS, webserver, and database performance tuning could all apply here) - e.g. "are you caching output?" / "do you have X plugin installed?" / "have you enabled or disabled X webserver feature?"

Whether or not a configuration is reasonable is subjective - given that you could easily see *many* "Dude, you need to do X" replies (as well as numerous requests for more information) this question seems too open-ended to be definitively answered in its present form - there are many potential configurations (and resulting memory requirements).

In the interest of providing resources which will help you determine the optimal configuration for your WordPress installations, I would recommend the following:

- [Steps to Optimize WordPress in Regard to Server Load?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/199/steps-to-optimize-wordpress-in-regard-to-server-load) - general answer at Wordpress.StackExchange.com
- [Testing WordPress Performance](http://codex.wordpress.org/Testing_WordPress_Performance) - advanced PHP/MySQL debugging instructions

The [Asking Better Questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/asking-better-questions/) article at the StackExchange Blog includes links to a number of suggestions which explain how to get the most out of asking questions - and you're always welcome to inquire at meta if you're unsure of whether a question meets a site's guidelines.

Comment: Thanks!  I would have been perfectly happy with the two links you gave me near the end as an answer to my original question on the main site.  The problem was that I had little idea where to start.  This gives me a place to start.  Cheers